# Can't render plot in shiny app on server but works in local and Rstudio server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, seurat

I've been stuck in this problem for days.

I'm building up a shiny app, where user chooses a dataset, server will then read corresponding .rds file, and render plots. The plotting tool requires package Seurat.

When I tested in local, it works. Then I deploy to the shiny server hosted in our university, the apps works well in Rstudio server also.

But, when I link through external, there are no plots rendered, saying "An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification."

I googled around and found possible environment-related causes:

1. file path
   I did check this, and since I've tested on the same machine (Rstudio server is the same as shiny server), this might not be the issue?
2. package
   When I load library(Seurat) at the beginning of my shiny app.R, the external link would fail but Rstudio server works well. So I tried ggplot2 to test if it is a package issue, it is loaded without problem, and plots rendered.

*To be specific, it seems to be Seurat compatibility issue, but why on the same machine it works in Rstudio server? Seurat community said this problem has been resolved in new CRAN release (3.2.0), but why am I still with this issue? How to fix it..??*

These are what I have noticed and hope you experts could give me some idea...

Here are the code to read .rds and render plots:

```
# read .rds
germ <- readRDS(file.path(paste("/srv/shiny-server/GermlinAtlas/data/",input$dataset,".rds", sep="")))

# render plot
observeEvent(input$dataset, {
  if (is.null(input$dataset)) return(NULL)
     if (is.null(input$gene)) return(NULL)
          infile <- isolate(input$dataset)
          germ <- readRDS(file.path(paste("/srv/shiny-server/GermlinAtlas/data/",infile,".rds", sep=""))) # read .rds
          gene <- isolate(input$gene)
          
          x <- rnorm(100)  # for ggplot test
          y <- rnorm(300)  # for ggplot test
          output$dim <- renderPlot({
            DimPlot(germ, reduction = "umap") # plot with Seurat
            plot(x,y[1:100]) # plot with ggplot2
          })
          output$featureplot <- renderPlot({
            FeaturePlot(germ, input$gene) # plot with Seurat
          })
        })
```

output from Rstudio server:
[image: output from Rstudio server:]

output from server (user end):
[image]

Comment: Please check the log of the app on the University server. That usually gives a better clue.  Also, the version of R and Seurat on the shiny server.  They may not be the same as the ones in your local or RStudio.

Comment: Agree with @YBS, see this [link for location of the logs on the server](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003717168-Shiny-Server-Error-Logs)

Comment: Check file permissions on the linux server.

Comment: Thank you @YBS. I've checked with the server administrator and problem resolved. I re-installed Seurat on shiny server and problem solved.